# need help to install Intel Gigabit LAN driver

Tags: debian, network-adapter, debian-wheezy

I am installing openMediaVault on my new build. the montherboard is Asrock B85M Pro4, and it has a onboard lan (Intel® Gigabit LAN)

OMV 0.5.0.24 cannot detect this onboard lan, where can I find hte linux driver and how to install it?

Comment: Issue the command: lspci -vnn | grep -A 10 -i Net . Post it above, pls.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Debian is that based on? If you aren't sure, post the contents of `/etc/debian_version`.

Then, you can [search google](https://www.google.com/search?q=installing%20intel%20network%20driver%20debian) for "intel network driver debian `<version>`" and you're bound to find multiple guides. The general process will be to download the driver archive from Intel for your specific NIC, copy it to your server with a USB drive or CD, and follow the instructions to compile/install the driver.